# How to use React-admin with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, react-admin

Is there a way to use [React-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin) package with Laravel?
I've read The docs there are some supported backend to use data provider of react-admin but laravel is not one of them.
Has anyone of you tried this package with laravel? or find a way to do that?
if not, could you suggest a dashboard package to use with laravel and react
thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no built-in dataProvider for Laravel CRUD APIs, as there is no standard for these APIs.

You'll have to build your API with Laravel (e.g. following the tutorial at https://auth0.com/blog/build-and-secure-laravel-api/), and then build a react-admin dataProvider for this API (following the tutorial at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviderWriting.html).